# Optimal block length for block bootstrap with multivariate time series

Tags: time-series, multivariate-analysis, econometrics, bootstrap, autocorrelation

I've got a multivariate time series $\mathbf{X}_t$, where $t$ is time and there are $p>1$ columns of $\mathbf{X}_t$.  There is autocorrelation in the data.  I'm interested in various functions of $\mathbf{X}_t$, and in quantifying their uncertainty.

For example, one of those functions is the distance of a given point $x$ from the mean of $\mathbf{X}_t$.  This involves calculating the mean and covariance matrix of $\mathbf{X}_t$ so that I can calculate a mahalanobis distance.  Since $\mathbf{X}_t$ is a time series, I'd like to use a stationary block bootstrap.

But how do I select a block length when I've got more than one variable?  The algorithm of [Politis & White](http://econ.duke.edu/~ap172/Politis_White_2004.pdf) (implemented in `b.star` in `np` in R) takes a vector of data.  Or, when applied to a matrix of data, returns a variable-wise optimal block length.

The OP in [this thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13675/alternative-to-block-bootstrap-for-multivariate-time-series) implies that the appropriate thing to do is to take the optimal (average) block length to be the maximum of the variable-wise optimal block lengths.  Is this correct?  Is it efficient?

Or, are there other approaches that don't even involve blocking?